# Android delete listview row in custom array adapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a listview that for displaying detail data.  I'm storing my data in an ArrayList of Strings.  However, some of the fields may not have any data to display, but I need to keep the array length the same to match a static titles array.  I can trap the empty data in my getView method in my custom base adaptor here:

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drug_detail_cell, parent, false);
        }

        // check array bounds
        if (position < getCount()) {

            // check for null items
            String item = items.get(position);
            if (item != null) {

                // get the text views
                TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                TextView sub = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_subtitle);

                title.setText(titles.get(position));
                sub.setText(item.toString());                   
            } else {
                // delete row
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

My problem is that while the data does not display, I still have an empty row in my listview.  My question is how do I delete that row?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: delete the data that populates your listview call `notifyDatasetChanged` on your adapter to refresh or update listview

Comment: find textViews id in if condition not out of it while you are inflating the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a tip: in else clause you return a empty view

```
else{
    View v = new View(context);
    v.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
    return v;
}
```

But if your list have divider, the divider below the empty view will be double.

In a different: I think you should handle all null data before getView call. I mean:
- In getCount(){
   loop and create a new map from position and not null data
   loop and count all data!=null; return count;
}

use new map in getView function.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I took your suggestion to handle null data before sending it to the array adapter. Since my data set is small, I created a loop to remove null data from my list and the associated header.

Answer (score 2):

For removing a row from the CustomListAdapter:

Remove the item from the ArrayAdapter from the specified index, after that call `notifyDatasetChanged` . It will update your listView.

In `CustomAdapterClass`:

```
@Override
public void remove(String object) {
    super.remove(object);

         // your other code
}
```

In `ListActivity` class:

```
CustomAdapterClass adap = new CustomAdapterClass();

adap.remove("hello world");

adap.notifyDatasetChanged(); // this will update your listView
```

My code is a `bare bone example` to depict how to achieve your goal.